# Embeddinig another website into a GWT application

Tags: gwt, iframe

I'm building a GWT application that looks great. At the end of the page I'd like to include a WordPress blog that I'm developing. In order to do that I want to use a com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame so that an IFrame gets created, and the Wordpress just gets seamlessly embedded.

I've built this and it seems to work, although there's a problem with the size of the IFrame. I'm not sure how it's getting sized, but it's too small so that scrollbars are thrown onto it. This makes the the embedding not so seamless.

What should I be doing so that this second webiste can be seamlessly embedded into my GWT app?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to make iframe as big as possible, and hope that there will be no unexpected scrollbars.

Also there is another way, if you have access to the innerDocument of iframe (if [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) doesn't stop you from doing this), you can compare its size against the size of iframe, and increase iframe height/width if necessary.

If blog is in another domain, you might try to use [cross-document messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging) to retrieve information about the size of document(this will not work in IE7,IE6 and you will have to put some additional JS on your blog).

Also you can include information from your blog without using iframes. You can simply pull RSS of your blog, parse it and display it in any way you like it.